# HTML - Form Submit Button Confirmation Dialog

Tags: php, javascript, form-submit

this is a general form code

```
<form name="search_form" action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="search_text">          
<input type="submit" name="search_bt" value="Go">
</form>
```

is there a way could have a confirmation dialog saying 'Yes'\'No' or 'Confirm'\'Cancel' etc...

One way i figured of dong is is with CSS Layer and JavaScript and Php... that have a php `isset(){}` chechk on the button and when set display a Div displayed with two buttons and `onclick=func()` JS function of those buttons have a php variable(flag) set and then i can `if(flag){}` to continue or skip some code...

well that is going to work and plus point is that i can have a well themed dialog box but i just wanna make my life easier...

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can also do it with one line in the form tag itself

```
<form action="exampleHandlerPage.php" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');">
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have 2 or more submit buttons in one form:

```
<input type="submit" value="Edit">
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Confirm, please.');">
```

The dialog shows up only when you click the `Delete` button.

Answer (score 2):

Using raw `javascript` without any div...

You can have this `function`

```
function confirmSubmit() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the form?")) {
    document.getElementById("FORM_ID").submit();
  }
  return false;
}
```

And you can call that function from the `onsubmit` event in the form, or on the `onclick` event in the `button`.

By the way, have you heard about [`JQuery`](http://jquery.com/). Its a JS Library with a lot of helpful things that give you a comfort and beauty way of coding javascript.

As an example of what you want to get done, take this [confirmation dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) from  [`JQuery`](http://jquery.com/) as example

Comment: i know jquery but not too muh.. and i would love to replace any JS thing with jquery... direct me to an example or sample

Comment: well jqyery is JS but still ;p

Comment: take this example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation and remember, that you have StackOverflow to help you in that transition... here are lot of GURU in JQuery...

Comment: thank you GURU JI... all these jQ ui items... how can i change their theme to go with my site design so that it doesn't look like a Dinner Jacket with a Baggy ;p

Comment: Guru where?... Jquery is CSS based... so you always can edit those CSS... anyhow, for your luck JQuery's people have made a ThemeRoller application, where you can select a them and/or pick a theme... just go to this link: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Answer (score -2):

```
<form action="<form handler>" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?')">
```

is this javascript can be store diferent from tag "form", replace

```
return confirm(...)
```

with something like

```
return sendata(...)
```