# HTML - Javascript | Form confirmation dialog with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dialog

I have a form where the user can either comment or close a ticket. As miss-clicks happen quite often I would like to ask the user if he is sure about closing the ticket. I already found this answer which works great in most cases:
[HTML - Form Submit Button Confirmation Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632530/html-form-submit-button-confirmation-dialog)

Unfortunately I use the same form with multiple buttons and want to only let it popup if the close button is used. Is there a simple solution without a lot of JavaScript?

Comment: Do you use bootstrap in your project?

Comment: nope, but jquery is already in use and loaded on that page.

Comment: You can try to switch your form `action` based on which button you pressed; or handle that on the backend, sending the button pressed `<button name="action" value="close">Close<button>`

Comment: mhh, but I can not get which has been used inside onsubmit?